# Cisco ASA 5505 (8.05): egress filtering intermittently

Tags: command-line-interface, cisco-asa

I'm not having any luck setting up egress filtering from the inside network to the outside, with the goal of denying all outbound traffic save for the HTTP Proxy (Squid) server that's also running DNS, NTP, etc.

If I remove all my ACL rules, it works fine: NAT's fine (double NAT's fine), I can surfing the web, etc.

However, what I *thought* was correct (and I've been through a pile of confusing documentation, some of it the wrong version, hence my woes in Cisco land), doesn't seem to work, albeit inconsistently.

Doing a telnet test, the first time I apply the `access-group` it works.  Hit CTRL-] to escape, hit up key, run command again, times out.  Remove all access-group assignments, doesn't work.  Come back to verify (as I'm typing this) and telnet works again.

Turned on debug logging, show log confirms that the packets are being discarded, but it doesn't look right and I think I may be applying my rules to the wrong interface or the wrong direction.

Here's some relative info:

Server: 192.168.2.5/24
Inside: 192.168.2.0/24
Outside: 10.0.0.254/24 (<-- test environment, has IP on my real LAN).

Here's my relative snippet of my config:

```
access-list server_out extended permit tcp host 192.168.2.5 any eq www
global (outside) 10 interface
nat (inside) 10 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
access-group server_out in interface inside
```

Again, a few minutes ago I had no access-group line and it worked.  I'm also trying this from several machines and another machine on 192.168.2.0/24 worked once or twice (even a few minutes ago), **even though there's no permit rule in there** as you can see, and I assumed the default deny rule would apply once you create an ACL.

**EDIT**

Here's some logging for your viewing pleasure -- this is a successful telnet to a webserver on my real LAN (10.0.0.12):

```
%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic TCP translation from inside:192.168.2.5/36097 to outside:10.0.0.254/57787
%ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 172 for outside:10.0.0.12/80 (10.0.0.12/80)  to inside:192.168.2.5/36097 (10.0.0.254/57787)
```

Here's the same request, several seconds later, no changes to config:

```
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.2.5/36100 to 10.0.0.12/80   flags FIN ACK  on interface outside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.2.5/36101 to 10.0.0.12/80 flags SYN  on interface outside
```

**EDIT2**

```
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.0(5)
!
terminal width 120
hostname some-host
enable password ***** encrypted
passwd ***** encrypted
names
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan3
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 10.0.0.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 2
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 2
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 2
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 2
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 2
 shutdown
!
boot system disk0:/asa805-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
access-list inside_out extended permit tcp host 192.168.2.5 any eq www
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging buffered debugging
mtu dmz 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
no failover
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 10 interface
nat (inside) 10 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
access-group inside_out in interface inside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect netbios
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect skinny
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect tftp
  inspect sip
  inspect xdmcp
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
Cryptochecksum:1234567890
: end
```

Comment: version's in the title: ASA 5505 8.0(5), added global line from config.

Comment: What does the rest of your ACL look like? Do you have any fix-ups enabled?

Comment: I'll vanilla it and post it in a second.

Comment: FYI, I've included some logging snippets above.

Comment: config posted in it's entirety.

Comment: Hmm nothings stands out there. Have you tried running packet-tracer while the ASA insn't allowing traffic?

Comment: @Zyper: the only thing that's odd is the interface configuration -- when I reload, I have to config e0/0 and `no shutdown` to bring it up.  Does that look right?  Also, e0/1 has no `switchport access` assigned to it (and it doesn't save when I copy to startup-config either), even though that interface isn't in play with this issue.

Comment: That doesn't sounds right. Makes my hardware issue alarm start to twinge. Is it new enough to still be within the 30 day (or whatever it is ) setup TAC support window? (or better yet have a smartnet contract?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is definitely wacky with my switch and/or cables: plugged machine directly into e0/2, works consistently, time after time.  Plug it back in, intermittent.  Odd that the log would show what it was showing, however.

EDIT

Yup, loop city, I'm surprised I could even get any packets out.  Word to the wise, kids: unplug your cables *after* you turn off port mirroring.